# Tensorflow music generation with lstm - model.fit not working

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a lstm model for music generation, but something seems to cause an error when calling model.fit().

```
# Compile the model
lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(lstm, show_shapes=True)

# Train the model
lstm.fit([trainChords, trainDurations], [targetChords, targetDurations], epochs=500)
```

```
Model: "model_6"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_19 (InputLayer)          [(None, 32)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_20 (InputLayer)          [(None, 32)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_18 (Embedding)       (None, 32, 64)       2048        ['input_19[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_19 (Embedding)       (None, 32, 64)       2048        ['input_20[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_9 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64)       0           ['embedding_18[0][0]',           
                                                                  'embedding_19[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 lstm_8 (LSTM)                  (None, 64, 512)      1181696     ['concatenate_9[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 dense_18 (Dense)               (None, 64, 256)      131328      ['lstm_8[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_19 (Dense)               (None, 64, 32)       8224        ['dense_18[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_20 (Dense)               (None, 64, 32)       8224        ['dense_18[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,333,568
Trainable params: 1,333,568
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I get the error that some shapes are not compatible, but I don't know how to fix this.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-8785c106bc4b> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Train the model
----> 7 lstm.fit([trainChords, trainDurations], [targetChords, targetDurations], epochs=500)

ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 64, 32) are incompatible
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update on building the model. Maybe the error is with the output layers(?)

```
# Define input layers
chordInput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (nChords))
durationInput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (nDurations))

# Define embedding layers
chordEmbedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nChords, embedDim, input_length = sequenceLength)(chordInput)
durationEmbedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nDurations, embedDim, input_length = sequenceLength)(durationInput)

# Merge embedding layers using a concatenation layer
mergeLayer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([chordEmbedding, durationEmbedding])

# Define LSTM layer
lstmLayer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)(mergeLayer)

# Define dense layer
denseLayer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256)(lstmLayer)

# Define output layers
chordOutput = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nChords, activation = 'softmax')(denseLayer)
durationOutput = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nDurations, activation = 'softmax')(denseLayer)

# nChords and nDurations are both 32

# Define model
lstm = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [chordInput, durationInput], outputs = [chordOutput, durationOutput])
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the outputs of `trainChords.shape`, `trainDurations.shape`, `targetChords.shape`, and `targetDurations.shape`? Most likely, one of the features is `(None)`.

Comment: trainChords: (6757, 32)
trainDurations: (6757, 32)
targetChords (6757,)
targetDurations (6757,)

Comment: Can you also update your question with how you defined your model? Not just `model.summary()`, but the code.

Comment: I added the additional code above.

Comment: Your LSTM layer probably wants `return_sequences=False` since you're feeding into Dense layers. Also, your two outputs are redundant. They use the same layer as input, with the same number of neurons with the same activation function. Their outputs would, in theory, be identical. I would either remove one, or duplicate the output of one layer so you're not spending extra resources training a redundant layer.